# React Table if Array is empty, no render

Tags: reactjs

I have 4 arrays which get data from an API, then i render 4 tables with those arrays, the problem here is, if one of those arrays is empty ( no data on the backend ) all the tables wont render..

```js
completedIssues: []
issuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint: []
puntedIssues: []
issuesCompletedInAnotherSprint: []


const filteredIssuesCompletedInAnotherSprint = this.state.issuesCompletedInAnotherSprint.map(item => (
        {
            assignee: item ? item.assigneeName : 'Empty',
            id: item ? item.id : 'Empty',
            key: item ? item.key : 'Empty',
            type: item ? item.typeName : 'Empty',
            summary: item ? item.summary : 'Empty',
        }
    ));


<ResponseTable data={filteredCompletedIssues} />
<ResponseTable data={filteredIssuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint} />
<ResponseTable data={filteredPuntedIssues} />
<ResponseTable data={filteredIssuesCompletedInAnotherSprint} />
```

ResponseTable
It receives an array of objects and render the data into the table...

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import "react-table/react-table.css";
 
export default class ResponseTable extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) { // Use Props
        super(props); // Use Props
        this.columnsBuilder = this.columnsBuilder.bind(this);

    }
    columnsBuilder () { //Remove data
        if(this.props.data == 0){
           return
        }
        const props = Object.keys(this.props.data[0]); //Use Props
        const columns = props.map( (item, index) => ({
            Header : item,
            accessor : item,
        }));

        const built = [
            {
                Header : this.props.header,
                columns,
            },
        ];        
        return built;
    }

        

    render() {


        return (
            <div>
                <ReactTable
                    data={this.props.data}
                    columns={this.columnsBuilder()} // Remove Props
                    defaultPageSize={10}
                    className="-striped -highlight"
                />
                <br />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**FIX** ResponseTable columnsBuilder()

```js
        if(this.props.data.length === 0) {
            return [{
                Header : this.props.header
            }];
        }
```

Comment: you can just check on array length before `render()` in `ResponseTable` else return null

Comment: What's the error? Show ur `ResponseTable` code.

Comment: @riwu , just updated with the ResponseTable & Error

Comment: Where are you creating the filtered arrays?

Comment: @J.Pichardo the API returns tons of properties which i don´t need, soo i just map those soo i cant pass them to my ResponseTable!

Comment: @zemmsoares good, but would you care to share the code

Comment: @J. Pichardo , this is my code, https://jsfiddle.net/eu2zw0p8/ 
Anything you don´t understand let me know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either do this in your parent container

```
{
  filteredCompletedIssues.length && <ResponseTable data={filteredCompletedIssues} />
}
```

OR you can do length check in your `ResponseTable` Component

```
render({data = []}) {

    if (!data.length) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
```

So your example would become:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import "react-table/react-table.css";
 
export default class ResponseTable extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) { // Use Props
        super(props); // Use Props
        this.columnsBuilder = this.columnsBuilder.bind(this);

    }
    columnsBuilder () { //Remove data
        if(this.props.data == 0){
           return
        }
        const props = Object.keys(this.props.data[0]); //Use Props
        const columns = props.map( (item, index) => ({
            Header : item,
            accessor : item,
        }));

        const built = [
            {
                Header : this.props.header,
                columns,
            },
        ];        
        return built;
    }

        

    render() {
        let { data = [] } = this.props;
        
        if(!data.length)
          return null;

        return (
            <div>
                <ReactTable
                    data={data}
                    columns={this.columnsBuilder()} // Remove Props
                    defaultPageSize={10}
                    className="-striped -highlight"
                />
                <br />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, today found the problem, on the columnsBuilder, i had to return the header! Regards

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the npm module **react-table**

```
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import "react-table/react-table.css";
```

then just set attribute **minRows** to 0 to tag ReactTable like as below code to stop rendering empty rows

```
<ReactTable data={tableDataArray} minRows={0} />
```